# Sending THIS from one function to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am posting a lot of code to prevent any questions but the thing is that `this` object is different inside of `ajax success` and different outside of it.

I tried to put `this` into the `var thisOb` and use it inside of ajax `success` function.
The code gives me message that `"thisOb is not defined"`. Is there any different way to transfer `this` from outside of ajax into the success function?

```
$(".editButton").on("click", function(){

    var textId = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
    var thisOb = $(this);

         $.ajax({
     type     : "POST",
     url      : "/get-textarea",
     data     : {
         textId: textId
     },
     success : function(msg) {
           $($thisOb).parent().prev().replaceWith("<textarea class='editArea' placeholder='"+msg+"'></textarea>");

      }

    });

});
```

Comment: You're using `$thisOb` when you declared it as `thisOb`.

Comment: Omg I am that stupid again XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a logical error:

```
$($thisOb).parent().prev()
```

Should be:

```
thisOb.parent().prev()
```

Is this a typo or? I have removed `$()` surrounding `thisObj` because it is meaningless. Already it is a jQuery object.

Comment: That helps me. Thank you a lot. I am just a blind retarded junior php developer XD

Comment: @divHelper11 No worries. I have added the explanation too. So kindly take care while coding... `:)`

Comment: @divHelper11 Do you mind accepting the answer if it works?

Answer (score 4):

You're close, but for an extra `$` or two:

```
var thisOb = $(this);
```

So now we have our outer `this` wrapped as a jQuery object.  Good.

```
$($thisOb).parent(
```

Two problems:

1. `$thisOb` doesn't exist. The variable is `thisOb`
2. The `$()` wrapper is redundant. `thisOb` is already wrapped.

```js
thisOb.parent(...)
```

should do the trick.